# How to deserialize POST request using a different Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to handle POST requests in my API endpoint using a different serializer than the one derived from Model and used for GET or PUT requests. The format of the POSTed messages is different from the Model and from GET/PUT and must be pre-processed before storing to the database.

As a demo of my problem I made a very simple model and the corresponding API view and serializer:

```
class Message(models.Model): 
    message = models.CharField(max_length = 500)

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('message',)

class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
```

That works well. Then I tried to override the MessageViewSet.create() to handle POST requests differently.

```
class MessageSerializer_FromTo(serializers.Serializer):
    sender = serializers.EmailField()
    recipient = serializers.EmailField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        message = "Message from <{sender}> to <{recipient}>".format(**validated_data)
        return Message(message)

class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    # Handle POST requests differently
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        message = MessageSerializer_FromTo(data = request.data)
        if message.is_valid():
            message.save()
            return Response(message.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(message.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Essentially I want to pass this JSON to POST /api/messages/

```
{"sender": "some@one.com", "recipient": "someone@else.org"}
```

GET /api/messages/1/ should return

```
{"message": "Message from <some@one.com> to <someone@else.org>"}
```

However the POST fails with this message:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/messages/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../rest_framework/fields.py", line 441, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
  File ".../rest_framework/fields.py", line 100, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'sender'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[...]
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `sender` on serializer `MessageSerializer_FromTo`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Message` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Message' object has no attribute 'sender'.
[26/Feb/2018 05:09:08] "POST /api/messages/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19059
```

This is just to demonstrate the problem obviously, I'm doing more complex things in my POST handler, but the error is like this.

Any idea how to achieve what I need? I.e. accept POST fields that are completely different from the Model fields?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** The complete code is here: https://github.com/mludvig/drf-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is with in your serializer. You are just passing model class `Message(message)` as the output of create function instead of Message object

```
class MessageSerializer_FromTo(serializers.Serializer):
    sender = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    recipient = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True)
    message = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, max_length = 500)   

    def create(self, validated_data):
        message = "Message from <{sender}> to <{recipient}>".format(**validated_data)
        return Message.objects.create(message=message)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help, still the same problem. I have added a link to github with the problem demo source: https://github.com/mludvig/drf-demo/tree/broken-post

Comment: serializer updated.Please try. Serializer was  expecting fields sender and recipient from the object. That was the problem

Answer (score 2):

To use different serializers depending on if the serializer will deserialize the data from the request or serialize it for the response, you can use [drf-rw-serializers](https://github.com/vintasoftware/drf-rw-serializers/).

It has generic classes to help you build views like the Django REST Framework ones, but, instead of using only one `serializer_class`, they use a `read_serializer_class` and a `write_serializer_class`.

You can read more instruction about installation and usage in the [documentation](http://drf-rw-serializers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get a different serializer depending on the method type by overriding the `get_serializer_class` method of you viewset

```
class MessageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Message

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializers_class_map = {
            'default': DefaultSerializer,
            'create': CreateMessageSerializer,
        }
        return serializers_class_map.get(self.action, serializers_class_map['default'])
```

You can also overrides the `to_representation` method of your `CreateMessageSerializer` to get a different output

```
class CreateMessageSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'sender', 'recipient'
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {
            'message': "Message from <{0.sender}> to <{0.recipient}>".format(instance)
        }
```

Comment: it looks promising but I can't make it work. I'm getting `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name "sender" is not valid for model "Message".` Here is the source: https://github.com/mludvig/drf-demo/tree/solution-luc