# How to use SlugRelatedField for incoming request (deserialise) and full serialiser for response for related fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My db model is of events and each event is connected to a venue.
When I retrieve a list of events I use:

```
venue = VenueSerializer(read_only=True)
```

When I post to my drf endpoint I use:

```
venue = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        allow_null=True,
        queryset=Venue.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        slug_field='id')
```

However this causes that in the response I recieve from the post request, the venue is serialised as a slug field. I want it to use the VenueSerialiser for the response.

I came accross https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035208/5683904 but it only works on the Viewset itself.

```
   #serializer_class = EventSerializer
   read_serializer_class = EventSerializer
   create_serializer_class = EventCreateUpdateSerializer
```

I need to build this functionality into the serialiser itself since it is shared with other components.

Comment: Can you please post your full serializer code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

The SlugRelatedField's `to_representation` method is coded to return the value of the `slug_field` keyword argument that you pass to it during initialization.

**Workarounds**

- Extend `SlugRelatedField` and override it's `to_representation` method to return the complete object instead of the slug. This could be a little tricky because the actual model instance isn't a part of the class.
- Have two fields, one for the slug and another for the actual object. This is way easier to implement.

Here's how you can implement the second workaround:

```
venue = VenueSerializer(read_only=True)
venue_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        write_only=True
        allow_null=True,
        queryset=Venue.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        slug_field='id')
```

**UPDATE**: This is apparently a pretty wanted feature in DRF. I've found a way to implement the first workaround as well. It deals with `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` but you could probably modify it to work with `SlugRelatedField` too. Here it is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from rest_framework import serializers


class AsymetricRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return self.serializer_class(value).data

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.queryset:
            return self.queryset
        return self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.all()

    def get_choices(self, cutoff=None):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if queryset is None:
            return {}

        if cutoff is not None:
            queryset = queryset[:cutoff]

        return OrderedDict([
            (
                item.pk,
                self.display_value(item)
            )
            for item in queryset
        ])

    def use_pk_only_optimization(self):
        return False

    @classmethod
    def from_serializer(cls, serializer, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        if name is None:
            name = f"{serializer.__class__.name}AsymetricAutoField"

        return type(name, [cls], {"serializer_class": serializer})
```

You can then use this field like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serilizers.ModelSerializer):

    bar = AsymetricRelatedField(BarSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

You can find the original discussion about this [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5206#issue-234442095https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5206#issue-234442095)

Comment: This is great! But I got an error:   source = AsymetricRelatedField(SourceSerializer())
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. Ideas?

Comment: You're instantiating an object of `SourceSerializer` instead of passing the actual class.